# Intercepting Network Requests in Python

Tags: python, http

I found [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) Python library for dealing with HTTP and was wondering if there was a way of intercepting requests made on a webpage using Python.

For example, if I wanted to grab a network request that matched a certain string and then get that requests content, could I do so?

Comment: Google up mitmproxy.

Comment: You can also check Charles.